# Splitting Up the Rest Api WADL?

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, jersey

Is there a way to Split up application.wadl in Java environment? 
Technology that are in place are
Jersey + Spring + spring MVC .

I want to split only application.wadl so that I can expose only those web services that I will be supporting for backward compatibility for my users. Also the authentication will be based on some different criteria. 
Does jersey provide any support for such requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

In general I was not able to find any way to split wadl generation logic by configuration. But here is hack you can perform. 
There is class  called GenerateWadlTask.java This basically does the wadl generation logic for jersey. 
You can just extend this class in your custom application wadl generation task and use it 
as per your logic. 
For code example just download the jersey server source jar and  look at the class. The logic is pretty straight forward.

hope this help.

**EDIT:- There is a maven plugin called enunicate http://enunciate.codehaus.org/ That will make your life easy.**